# SlidingMenu cannot highlight selected item

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am using SlidingMenu for Android and I have a "menu fragment" like this:

```
public class MenuListFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
        ArrayAdapter<String> colorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        setListAdapter(colorAdapter);
        getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.menu_selector);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
        Fragment newContent = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                etc...
        }
        if (newContent != null)
            switchFragment(newContent);
        v.setSelected(true);
        lv.setSelected(true);
    }

    private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (getActivity() == null)
            return;

        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        activity.switchContent(fragment);
    }
}
```

selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

    <!--<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_pressed="true"/>-->
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <!--<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_activated="true"/>-->
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" />

</selector>
```

and list layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
```

Once one item in the menu is clicked the menu is hidden (as supposed). But when the menu is displayed again there are no more selected item.

Is there a way to keep the item selected?

**UPDATE**

Following the suggestion of Shereef Marzouk I have changed:

```
public class MenuListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private View selectedView;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
        Fragment newContent = null;
        switch (position) {
            // stuff
        }
        if (selectedView != null) selectedView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.aqincolor));
        v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.espresso));
        selectedView = v;
        if (newContent != null)
            switchFragment(newContent);
    }

    ...
}
```

In this case it works but I don't get the sense of having a `menu_selector.xml` that doesn't switch even calling `super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: "In this case it works but I don't get the sense of having a menu_selector.xml", the menu selector helps you create a feedback effect (touch down effect), but the menu that is shown after the touching of a menu item is an entirely other menu than the one the user touched, they are not linked and they don't know anything about your loaded activity, this is why you have to change the color manually, at least this is how I understand it, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did in my application:

```
final Class<?> currentClass = getActivity.getClass();
        switch (position) {
          case 0: //Menu
            cls = MainNavigationActivity.class;
            if (currentClass.equals(cls)) {
              view.setBackgroundColor(parent.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.selectedMenuBackground));
            }
            break;
        }
```

When the menu is initialized check which class you have initialized and depending on that change the BG color

Comment: thanks for your reply. Please look my answer I have still a doubt.

Comment: Thank you. I dont't know whether it is a correct way, but this is the only solution worked for me

Comment: P.S. I used it in getView() of the sliding menu's list adapter